# Cannot fetch Steam Avatar session to my Index.php

Tags: php, session

Alright, so I have set up all my necessary sessions to fetch them into my index.php.
What I want is to show the steam profile avatar and the steam name at the top of my dropdown menu after they have logged inbut I can't seem to fetch the sessions. 
I just get this: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3sKm.png](http://Image%20Source%20Error)

Here is my UserInfo (the api sessions): http://pastebin.com/7E2Za8MV 
Here is the code I've written in attempt of trying to fetch the steam avatar session:

```
<img height="15" src="<?php echo("{$_SESSION['steam_avatar']}"."<br />");?>">
```

Comment: Have you started session at the top of your PHP script? Because right now I don't see any `session_start();`, anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Check the quotes carefully.

```
<img height="15" src="<?php echo $_SESSION['steam_avatar'].'<br />');?>">
```

Also check `session_start();` Or check using this `echo $_SESSION['steam_avatar'];`